# Python RSA: Will "crypto.sign" sign a String with lowercase hex digest

Tags: python, rsa, sha

I used the python lib `OpenSSL.crypto` to load a `.p12` file, and then I used the `hashlib.sha256` to generate a digest of my data. The question is that I cannot get the "signature" I want. Is it because the python lib, `crypto.sign(pkey, data, digest)` used the lowercase `a-z` rather than the uppercase `A-Z` in the `hexdigest`? The code is shown here.

The signature is different from the one generated by another method of `JAVA-RSASHA256`.
Java used the digest below: The final String is with upper format `A-F`.

```java
import java.security.MessageDigest;
char hexDigits[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
try {
    byte[] btInput = content.getBytes("UTF-8");
    MessageDigest mdInst = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    mdInst.update(btInput);
    byte[] md = mdInst.digest();
    int j = md.length;
    char str[] = new char[j * 2];
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        byte byte0 = md[i];
        str[k++] = hexDigits[byte0 >>> 4 & 0xf];
        str[k++] = hexDigits[byte0 & 0xf];
    }
    return new String(str);
} catch(Exception e) {
    return null;
}
```

While I used the python code to generate the digest below.

```py
from OpenSSL import crypto
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256

data = 'hello world!'
hash_256 = hashlib.sha256()
h_sha256 = hash_256.copy()
h_sha256.update(data.encode('utf-8'))
sha256_str = h_sha256.hexdigest()
print('output:', sha256_str)
#The "print-result" contains only lower-format 'a-f'.
```

Will `crypto.sign(pkey, data, digest)` of Python uses the lowercase digest to generate a signature? So the signature is different from that of java because java takes the uppercase?
**The following code is how I import my `.p12` file to sign a String.**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# load OpenSSL.crypto
from OpenSSL import crypto
import hashlib

psw = b'123456'
p12 = crypto.load_pkcs12(open(r"D:\tasks\private_key.p12", 'rb').read(), psw)
pkey = p12.get_privatekey()
data = 'hello world!'
my_signature = crypto.sign(pkey, str.encode(data), 'sha256')
```

Comment: The upper or lower case is of no consequence since only the actual raw bytes are used in signing, and those are the same. You have not provided an example of the signature you "want", and your first two code snippets don't produce signatures at all, they produce hashes.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have already solved the signing problem. Furthermore, the upper case and the lower case do have an influence on the digest.